# Что я делаю не так и получаю: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'patients' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Я создал контекст и в дочерние элементы пытаюсь передать значения:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import Content from './components/Content';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import PatientService from './components/services/PatientService';

const PatientContext = createContext([{}]);

function App() {
  const [selectedPatient, setSelectedPatient] = useState([]);
  const [patients, setPatients] = useState([{ name: "Username", age: 19 }]);

  async function patientsHasChanged() {
    const patientService = new PatientService();
    const loadedPatients = await patientService.getPatients();
    setPatients(loadedPatients);
  };

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <PatientContext.Provider value={{selectedPatient, setSelectedPatient, patients, patientsHasChanged}}>
        <Sidebar />
        <Content />
      </PatientContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

В одном из компонентов (`Sidebar`) я достаю некоторые значения:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import PatientContext from '../App';

const Sidebar = () => {
    const {patients, setSelectedPatient} = useContext(PatientContext);

    return (
        <div className='sidebar'>
            <div className='search'>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Search' />
                <a href="/TechTask/new"><button>New patient</button></a>
            </div>
            <div className='list'>
                <ul>
                    {patients.map((p) =>
                        <li onClick={setSelectedPatient}>
                            <div className='name'>
                                {p.name}
                            </div>
                            <div className='age'>
                                {p.age}
                            </div>
                        </li>)
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Структура папок:

```
App.js
components-
---Sidebar.jsx
---Content.jsx
```

Но в результате получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'patients' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

Насколько я понимаю - это потому, что из контекста достается пустой элемент, но почему? Ведь в контексте есть данные.

Comment: на какой именно строчке происходит данная ошибка?

Comment: В строчке: `const {patients, setSelectedPatient} = useContext(PatientContext);`

Comment: покажи как ты импортируешь `PatientContext` в файле компонента Sidebar

Comment: `import PatientContext from '../App';` App выше в структуре папок, поэтому импорт выглядит логичным и правильным

Comment: за исключением того, что он неправильный :):):)

Comment: отредактируй вопрос, чтобы явно было видно все необходимые экспорты и импорты :-)

Comment: Отредактировал, смотрю экран монитора и очень тщательно ищу где же я мог накосячить с импортами. Если действительно проблема в такой мелочи, то буду крайне обескуражен о_О

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в неверном использовании импорта

```
import Name from '...'
```

соответствует дефолтному экспорту, в данном случае это `export default App;`

Далее идет попытка получить контекст по компоненту и, закономерно, возвращается `undefined`.

для решения, нужно экспортировать сам контекст

```
export const PatientContext = createContext([{}]);
```

А также импортировать именно его:

```
import { PatientContext } from '../App';
```

Comment: Дааааа, вот это я знатно тупанул. Все действительно так, спасибо!